# Multiple TextBox Readonly at once

Tags: jquery

In this table

```
<table id="tbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="nm" value="Product A" name="nm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qt" value="" name="qt"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="pr" value="220" name="pr"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qr" value="2" name="qr"/></td>
  </tr>...
```

how can I specify readonly to multiple textboxes at once. This does not work

```
$('.nm, .qt, .qr').prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: That should work. Have you checked whether the use selector actually matches any elements?

Comment: It works here - http://jsfiddle.net/6Rc78/

Comment: Silly browser cache. Hit Ctrl+F5 and started working!! Thanks for your help

Comment: Care to look at questions/23643853 please. Thanks,